# Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoid and convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, ellipsoids

I need your help in solving the following.

---

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty]$ be a convex function and $L = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \leq 1\right\rbrace$ be a sub-level set of $f$ (We assume that $L$ is not empty). 
>  Let $E = (G,v)$ denote the minimum volume ellipsoid that encloses $L$, which is centered at $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix which can represent the ellipsoid. 
>  Then, does $f$ attains it's minimal value (minimum value) at $v$ (the center of the enclosing ellipsoid of $L$)?

---

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To illustrate, let’s take the simplest possible dimension for this, n=1. An ellipsoid in one dimension is of the form $$(x-a)^2=b^2$$

Let $f$ be defined by 
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
|x|&, x <0\\
\frac{x}{3}&, x \ge 0\end{array}\right.$$

Then $L=[-1,3]$ and $E$ is given by $(x-1)^2=2^2$. In other words, $v$ is the point $x=1$ but $f$ attains its minimum at $x=0$.

Example in 2D

Let $f$ be defined by 
$$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
|x|+|y|&, x<0\\
\frac{x}{3}+|y|&, x \ge 0\end{array}\right.$$

Then the minimum of $f$ is at the origin, but $$E: \frac{(x-1)^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{4}{3}}=1$$

has center at $(1,0)$.

It is just as easy to construct an example in higher dimensions as well.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, however I see that the way I had described the question is flawed, what I meant that given an ellipsoid which is the minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid which encloses $L$, then there exists a v such that occurs. I did not meant given $v$, let $E$ be the minimal volume ellipsoid which CAN enclose $L$.

Comment: @user3492773 In my answer too v is not given, right?. It comes out of whatever happens to be the minimum volume ellipsoid given the f. Of course, because we’re aiming for a counter example, I deliberately chose the function f so that what comes put to be its min vol ellipsoid, its center is not going to coincide with the min of f. The answer goes: start with f, find its L, then E and hence v.

Comment: I’m not understanding the difference in your comment between “min volume ellipsoid enclosing L” and “min volume ellipsoid that CAN enclose L”. Since we are taking about THE smallest ellipsoid that encloses L, there is only one - it can enclose is equivalent to it does enclose. And its center is uniquely defined. Do you have an example to illustrate the difference?

Comment: Put another way: forget that I wrote a complete answer - what if I just give you the f in each case- and you go ahead and find L, E and v yourself (this is the question, right?). Do you find the v to be at the min of the function?

Comment: I dont see why it would! however i did not know (In your example, it shows otherwise). Also, if E was the maximal inscribed ellipsoid, the same answer would be tweaked to get similar example?

Comment: @user3492773 Indeed, the same f would provide an example for the case of the maximum inscribed ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1):

No, certainly not.
Write $f = f_1 + f_2$, where $f_1 = \delta_L : \mathbb R^n \to \{0,\infty\}$ is the indicator function of $L$ and $f_2 : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is an arbitrary convex function. Then, the minimum value of $f$ is the minimal value of $f_2$ on $L$ and this can be any point in $L$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, do look the my comment towards @Mathemagical.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. My answer tries to answer the question that you have posted. I do not know the question you tried to ask.